# Create BindableProperty for CornerRadius

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I've been trying to create some BindableProperty to my customView, I've been able to create a string and double one but I'm not getting the CornerRadius one right.

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty GeneralCornerRadiusProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GeneralCornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(NumberChoseView), new CornerRadius(24));

    public CornerRadius GeneralCornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(GeneralCornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(GeneralCornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Border xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MauiAppTest.Templates.Views.NumberChoseView"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppTest.Templates.Views"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        x:Name="self"
        x:DataType="local:NumberChoseView"
        BindingContext="{x:Reference self}">

    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="{Binding GeneralCornerRadius}" />
    </Border.StrokeShape>

</Border>
```

In the ContentPage it's used like this

```xml
<views:NumberChoseView GeneralFontSize="55"
                       Quantity="12"
                       GeneralCornerRadius="30">
</views:NumberChoseView>
```

I have tried every CornerRadius format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

There is a known issue on GitHub : [Border does not change rendering when modifying StrokeShape properties](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13988). That means if you use Bindings for CornerRadius and change the value, the CornerRadius will not reflect the change.

This issue is now fixed in .NET8, which I have tested and confirmed.

If you just want to set a value  `GeneralCornerRadius="30"` and not use Bindings for **GeneralCornerRadius**, you could try my original post.

Otherwise, it is fixed in .NET8 and you may try it.

---

**Original post**

That's the issue with Binding.

Make some changes to your NumberChoseView:

1.Remove the following two lines:

```
    x:DataType="local:NumberChoseView"
    BindingContext="{x:Reference self}"
```

2.Use x:Reference Binding expression for **CornerRadius**

```
 <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="{Binding GeneralCornerRadius,Source={x:Reference self}}" />
```

So the NumberChoseView should be like this:

```
<Border xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="dfafdasf.NumberChoseView"
             ...
             x:Name="self" 
             >

    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="{Binding GeneralCornerRadius,Source={x:Reference self}}" />
    </Border.StrokeShape>
</Border>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: With this type of binding the value can't be changed in runtime right?

Should i use this type of binding for every property that doesn't need to be changed in runtime and use the BindableProperty - Property bind (as shown with my example) only with the properties that will change in runtime?

Comment: Ok no, i tried to change the value on runtime and for a type double property it changes but not for the cornerradius

Comment: Yes exactly, we cannot change the cornerradius in runtime. That's the issue for .NET7 and .NET6. But it is now fixed in .NET8.  BindableProperty also works fine.